# Caused by: Zip file '/Users/***/.gradle/jetified-SettingsLib-api.jar' already contains entry 'com/android/settingslib/R$anim.class', cannot overwrite

Tags: android, aar, android-13

I am creating an independent system UI project using Android's open-source 13 and encountered an error when introducing the Setting.aar package。

anybody get this question。

```
Failed to transform WifiTrackerLib-.aar (:WifiTrackerLib:) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.status=integration, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /Users/****/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fb27335a3bda13f34761986f27530b4d/transformed/jetified-WifiTrackerLib.aar.
         > Zip file '/Users/***/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/857f78488989ec604802c3978f1d53b6/transformed/jetified-WifiTrackerLib-api.jar' already contains entry 'com/android/wifitrackerlib/R$array.class', cannot overwrite
```